# Sencha Touch: Disable scrolling for a Panel, List, or DataView?

Tags: scroll, sencha-touch, extjs

I see that panels have the option to set `scroll:` to horizontal or vertical, but is there any way to do something like: `scroll: 'false'`? I've tried such without luck.

I have a DataView nested in a Panel. I can set the scroll direction of each independently, but I want the DataView not to scroll at all.

[Any tips will earn answer points and a digital high five. Heck, I'll even throw in a bonus high SIX!]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, turns out by fudging around a bit (as I've learned to do with poorly documented Sencha Touch) that disabling the scroll can be done as follows:

```
scroll: false
```

Note the absence of single or double quotes when setting `scroll:` to `false`. The values `horizontal` and `vertical`, however can be done with single or double quotes.

Comment: Oh, so it looks like I owe myself a high SIX! (^6!!!) But sadly, no answer points for answering your own question.

Comment: In sencha touch 2.3.1 there is no property named scrollable on the Ext.dataview.List. Any idea on how to disable scrolling ?

Answer (score 4):

I think this relates to the fact that in javascript, strings (e.g. 'false', "false") are evaluated to true if not null.  So "false", 'false', "true", 'true', 'junk', 'absce' all evaluate to true.  So by setting the attribute value scroll:'false' or scroll:"false" it is actually setting it to true.   Using the non-quoted *false* on the other hand is actually passing a proper boolean false value.

Answer (score 3):

For Sencha Touch 2 users scroll can be disabled using the following config:

```
config: {
   scrollable: false
}
```

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Panel-cfg-scrollable

Answer (score 0):

You should **setScrollable** to **false** for your component.

Here is the example:

```
//'.items' CSS class or other selector
var itemsId = pageEl.up('.items').id;

//Find component
var itemsCmp = Ext.getCmp(itemsId);

//You can skip two previous lines in case you already have needed component
itemsCmp.setScrollable(false);
```